# Restoring variables in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

After training my model and saving the variables into a checkpoint file, I want to restore this variables so that I can test it with new data, and compute for the output.

What are the steps for this? Do I need to assign the "names" of these variables explicitly? In order to use them when I restore my model?

Comment: See this question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/33759623/712995

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow: how to save/restore a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759623/tensorflow-how-to-save-restore-a-model)

Comment: Maybe not, my question is, do I need to explicitly name my variables?